# Using DNSSEC with GoDaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, godaddy, dnssec

This is my setup

**Domain:** nginx-repo[.]com (Registered at GoDaddy)
**Nameserver:** A DigitalOcean VM running BIND on Debian 7

I created a zone for the above mentioned domain on my VM then used `dnssec-keygen` and `dnssec-signzone` to setup and sign the zone file.

The DS records

```
# cat dsset-nginx-repo.com.
nginx-repo.com.         IN DS 22728 7 1 7EAA739B73EDB97A3E352435F7064D9865AAF45E
nginx-repo.com.         IN DS 22728 7 2 6812A504A54E37DDCBD3EB2913A53336AD4D132C619F7F98B45F91A6 98131231
```

Now I logged into GoDaddy and tried entering the first DS record but got the error - **We are unable to validate your data at this time. Please try again later. If the problem persists, contact customer support.**

So I contacted GoDaddy via live chat and in short this is what happened.

**Me:** I'm getting so and so error when entering DS records
**They:** You **need Premium DNS** for DNSSEC
**Me:** But your documentation (http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6135/dnssec-faq) says I can configure *Self-Managed* DNSSEC with custom nameservers
**They**: Yes but you must have control over signing your zones
**Me**: I do the NS is hosted on a DigitalOcean VPS on which I have root access
**They**: But not in THIS account the zone file must be controlled by THIS account.

After some argument this is what they said

> The Domain name has to be within the same account with the Premium DNS ... most people will also have their VPS on the same account to prevent cross account errors like this

**Me:** :-S :-S :-S :-S

What is wrong here? Did I configure DNSSEC incorrectly in BIND?

Or do I have to signup with GoDaddy VPS to use Self-Managed DNSSEC :-D :-D

Here is a `dig` output

```
# dig DNSKEY +multiline  nginx-repo.com @dns.nginx-repo.com

;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> DNSKEY +multiline nginx-repo.com @dns.nginx-repo.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31501
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nginx-repo.com.                IN DNSKEY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nginx-repo.com.         86400 IN DNSKEY 257 3 7 (
                                AwEAAaqoS3iOSx6zKrlp28xrLfL4VX4OTCOc5wiUQYy0
                                xV0Z1Duq2NHEbJAniAF9K4Hgp+YbvpheF667+1gKLeuc
                                RO6DiHAp08kQf45fo6NVvdWSqQlH5JS9bdawx1BtKi/k
                                BXLWtL+j9wJ+Xn2MmwyAvSEZ+XBnSnZmSkK5AqKd99A5
                                /UTNazgnwrsVIeBswczh+L/Fl55dAfoJfeFdBjK0ttHg
                                mrydkfYV+pK/poMQEbIcfxA3CHql7J7aXQWsqVozlXwM
                                mDZ9rJ9dtY4fySSA5apF1P5ulnvSRyvpRHP9Nr6IDP9q
                                PmIkmQYy3N+wADIbSvAloCEhyHy3hHzmD/B033O7Pk1T
                                KjVx9Xiso3NvT2lipgZdWUffiC5Az3XJNeAbp1nNg8Rn
                                5ZDyLf1yusBzxvV+bjybKBxj5SQHOJWtPu8BuczEEcW+
                                mSOtRPxPg90idbMGrW3QgVTqx3fp/CfJbDpffZ8scpOg
                                dFoQ9/sjib/BYt8zgadU0fmQD0MvGm9OLB713I9Zbi/I
                                lMhephDaFcK4BRRY08BYwh53pWw32OnUmj6aqPFOsok9
                                pYVkpzFDHifw4dcvGj0aFk4FKcNyXDqLwpT4rQNDRWaN
                                7WRLViglBzVEfesGZN6GGgL9gJIfLuCovbLEhRIUYql/
                                wNG83GKMAK7Nx7gvqfeKsmesYeKL
                                ) ; key id = 22728
nginx-repo.com.         86400 IN DNSKEY 256 3 7 (
                                AwEAAc+8SlNMiwtQT6/1NitlWBPg7dx53A7cmP3tg75Q
                                PlEqQrTRzf4+j5JPTfV/dHjwd4lXpEYxi+YMT8e3q9KM
                                SyBuZSIGJc+rBsdPDqaWPLL8J8/D3mK4cGOPvD8BIs4V
                                Zo+v9sMm4PQsXkcntGJ45UPTflGghss8MNveg1U/+irL
                                oIOm7jP2iLS6lPdhxrpuoXH8nBMIvjMxAQBRAlxkUjO1
                                X9OOw+G/rCrcjyv7gyt7ihy1+CZCrrQE7Mg629BHCkMv
                                40bLt5SdW9+IXe4soVNo+4gR9XgGDXTikztN/ZoAAjiJ
                                Z9uwsJ3C1FGxwyH3/EwafhxXXDnDmHL3+oCUvfs=
                                ) ; key id = 2579

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.241.253.191#53(192.241.253.191)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 25 19:42:10 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 840
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved. It was a problem at GoDaddy's end.

I created a ticket and received the following reply after **61 hours**.

> Our validation web service calls out to the registrar back-end web service, which calls out to the registry for DNSSEC validation. Many times the call to the registry times out. This is most likely why you were receiving errors.

If the person on the chat had told me this it would've saved me a lot of time and also the need to create a topic here.

Comment: Good old GoDaddy. Living up to their reputation.